# Is there ICAO document that describes MVA criteria?

Tags: icao-sarps, aircraft-operations

According [Skybrary article](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Minimum_Vectoring_Altitude_(MVA)) the minimum vectoring altitude in each sector provides **1000 ft** above the highest obstruction in non-mountainous areas and **2000 ft** above the highest obstacle in designated mountainous areas. Could someone advise ICAO or EUROCONTROL manual / document that contains definition of minimum vectoring altitude (MVA)? Which manual should I use to find information about **1000 ft** above the highest obstruction in non-mountainous areas and **2000 ft** above the highest obstacle in designated mountainous areas as MVA criteria?

Comment: I believe there is no definition, that needs to be confirmed by someone from ATC though. Eurocontrol [refers to Skybrary](https://ext.eurocontrol.int/lexicon/index.php/Minimum_Vectoring_Altitude). ICAO recommends an obstacle clearance in PANS-OPS v2 (Doc 8168): "*A minimum of 300 m (984 ft) of clearance shall be provided over all obstacles within the area [...]*", and for mountainous areas in PANS-OPS v1: "*Over high terrain or in mountainous areas, additional obstacle clearance up to a total of 600 m (1 969 ft) is provided to accommodate [...]*"

Comment: Following the lack of definition at international body level, local AIP have to provide [their own](https://www.lvnl.nl/eaip/2021-04-08-AIRAC/html/eAIP/EH-ENR-1.6-en-GB.html#ENR-1.6).